# Get two max values from table

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g

I'm having a busy day trying to achieve the desired result. Here's my table.

```
item    loc price   START_DATE  CALC_DATE
item1   1243    1,16    18.04.16    18.04.13
item1   1243    1,20    18.02.20    18.02.19
item1   1243    1,20    18.02.17    18.02.16
item1   1243    1,20    18.02.15    18.02.14
item1   1243    1,18    18.01.10    18.01.09
item2   1243    2,23    18.03.20    18.03.19
item2   1243    2,77    18.02.27    18.02.26
item2   1243    2,42    18.01.24    18.01.23
item2   1243    3,21    18.01.05    18.01.04
item2   1243    2,77    18.01.04    18.01.03
```

And this is the desire output.

```
item    WH  actual price    old price
item1   1243    1,16    1,2
item2   1243    2,23    2,77
```

I can get the "actual price" by doing max(STAR_DATE) and max(CALC_DATE), but cant get the second max dates.
Any ideas?

Thank you!

Comment: im assuming old price for item 1 should be 1,20?

Comment: What's supposed to happen when there's a tie for 2nd? Would you expect three records or still only two?

Comment: yes, old price should be 1,20.
if there's a tie, it should give two records only. one for the actual price and another for the old price

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work for you:

```
select item, loc, max(case when rownum=1 then price else null end) actual_price, 
max(case when rownum=2 then price else null end) old_price
from
(select *,  row_number() over(partition by item, loc order by start_date desc) rownum
from yourtable)a
group by item, loc
```

Comment: Thanks for your feedback, but it gives me thies error:
00923. 00000 -  "FROM keyword not found where expected"
Error at Line: 4 Column: 10
Any ideas?

Comment: Not sure worked fine for me - make sure you copied the whole query correctly and you replaced ‘yourtable’ With your table name

Comment: I had to change the "*" for some columns of the table, and it worked as i need!
Thanks for the help

Comment: OK great glad to hear!